# Выбрать из массива несколько максимальных значений

Tags: php, массивы, данные

Есть массив $arr = [8, 4, 12, 9,17,22, 6 ,25,27,5];
Нужно взять из этого массива 2-3 самых больших значений.
Кол-во элементов массива может быть разным - формируется от другого источника, чтобы отсортировать usort не вижу вариант.Функция max берет одно максимальное значение.

Comment: Так отсортируйте просто по возрастанию или по убыванию и возьмите элементы через slice

Comment: Смахивает на задание - автор, где собственные попытки сделать требуемое?

Comment: а зачем здесь usort-то?

Comment: Quckselect. [Первый попавшийся пример на PHP](https://junaidhassanalvi.wordpress.com/2015/12/20/in-php-how-to-get-kth-smallest-element-in-an-unordered-list-answer-is-quickselect/)

Answer (score 2):

Сортируем в обратном порядке и делаем срез с первого элемента в размере 2-ух штук

```
$arr = [8, 4, 12, 9,17,22, 6 ,25,27,5]; 

rsort($arr);
$result = array_slice($arr, 0, 2);
```

или

```
sort($arr);
$result = array_slice($arr, -2);
```